# Override a style in Android without modifying layout file

Tags: android

My experience up until now when dealing with styles has been to create a style.xml file and create the properties I want for the style. If I want my style to be based on an existing style, I use the parent attribute. I then specify the style inside of my layout file on the controls that I want to apply the style to.

Where I am at a loss is when I want to use system styles and only update certain properties. I am wondering whether I can leave the layout files alone and not bother applying any styles to the controls. Instead, I would somehow update the property of the system style and that would update everywhere in my app where that style is already being used by default.

More specifically, I want to change the background color of the Actionbar but haven't found a way of doing it other than the way I described above.

Comment: Because you have to go into the layout file and change it there. Suppose it wasn't the actionbar but a textview and you wanted to have the default color set to something different than the system color. You would have to set the style in ALL layout files where you are using a textview. Digging a little deeper, I think that this is the solution but am not sure http://stackoverflow.com/a/21540183/753632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for themes, which are collections of styles, applied either globally throughout the application, or for each Activity in particular. Start with [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) document and investigate further.